# What's the best way to check for prerequisites

Tags: wix, burn

I'm building a bootstrapper installer with custom UI. It has some prerequisites that it needs to check before installing and if anything is missing - show it in UI.

I have 2 possibilites:

- Check it in XML of my bootstrapper with utils like RigustrySearch
- Check it in UI and set some variables in bootstrapper
- Have a custom extension and call it from XML

What is the best approach here?

Pros for having it in XML:

- Native way of doing it

Pros for having it in UI part:

- I could organize code nice and clean
- I can have a separate Dll for prerequisites validation, or even a nuget package
- I have way more flexibility and it's more simple to make complex assertions
- I can have extra information for each prerequisite, like license info and user friendly name

Pros for having a custom extension:

- Don't need to fiddle with variables in XML

I personally am more inclined towards the second option as option one is going to make my XML huge and more difficult to read if I have a lot of prerequisites. Option 3 is nice, but It's more difficult to show the user friendly name for a prerequisite and its license information in UI. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this really depends on what your prerequisites are, and how you intend to handle their presence/absence.  Here's my personal preference.

Generally, If I'm going for a managed bootstrapper application I'll have that do the detection of the prereqs if I then need some input from the user, ie. an installation directory, credentials, or whatever.  I then pass some values from the managed app, into burn variables, and in turn into Wix properties for the individual msi's to respond to.  This is my most used approach.

If all of your prerequisites are part of your bundle anyway, and you don't need any interaction from the user, I tend to go ahead as if I'm installing each package, and the packages themselves are responsible for handling their own upgrade/installation not required behaviours.  ie. bundling .Net, or 3rd party installers with your application.

I tend to avoid custom actions for this sort of work, I find them a bit cumbersome when trying to deal with all the successful/failed paths of install/upgrade/repair/uninstall etc.

I think it's a bit subjective to your specific use case, and there's not a single best approach for all situations.

Comment: Agreeing with "go ahead as if I'm installing each package, and the packages themselves are responsible for handling their own upgrade/installation not required behaviours." Unless they have complete and accurate documentation, only they, themselves, can handle detect conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I ought to clarify that I don't do things in a bootstrapper/managed BA that pertain to third party installers, only to my own.